# Add color to specific word in PHP table cell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to color the word "Pizza" in class "status", which is inside my HTML table, which gets data from a database with PHP.

```
      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
        <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td class="status"><?php echo $row['pojem'];?></font></td>
            <td><font color="brown"><?php echo $row['kratica'];?></font></td>
            <td><font color="brown"><?php echo $row['nem'];?></font></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
<script>
$('.status:contains("Pizza")').css('color', 'red');
</script>
```

Comment: as far as I'm aware with the source code you have provided doesn't show what the elements will contain so `contains("Primary")` is useless. It will target elements with "Primary" in, not based on the class name.

Comment: Side note: `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: Since this is db-related, you may want to edit your post to contain the schema/values for this, unless  you're 100% certain that a row does contain the word "Primary" and a side note about this is; it's a mysql reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html, so we don't know if that's playing a role in this or not. Edit: Well, I guess I can throw this in the water then, given the stealth edit.

Comment: You also need to target the `<td>` here and you've a stray `</font>` tag.

Comment: Oh, so this went from `Primary` to `Pizza`, all of a sudden.

Comment: To mark found word use `<mark/>` tag. I hate div-itis and table-tr-td-fint-itis. I say "no" for deprecated `<font/>` and for `<span/>` in this case. Write the code semantically. Use CSS to change visible behaviour. Do not forget about `::after` and `::before` if count of containers is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following jQuery code and set CSS class `colord` with the color or the style you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td.status').each(function(){
   text = $(this).html();
   $(this).html(text.replace('Pizza','<span class="colord">Pizza</span>')); // html is used instead of text
});

})
```

#### Edit

The `text` method is replaced with `html` method to make void HTML escape in the string.

Comment: You might want to change the "Primary" to "Pizza", given the OP stealth edited the post. So, you may not have seen that.

Comment: This code literally changes the word "Pizza" to "<span class="colord">Pizza</span>"

Comment: For instance, it changes the sentence "My favourite food is Pizza" to "My favourite food is <span class="colord">Pizza</span>"

Comment: @kac26 So, What is the problem?

Comment: @saidbakaR this is the image of my table cell edited wih your code https://imgur.com/a/W8qDA

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand correctly then this is good solution

```
<!-- populate table from mysql database -->
        <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){ ?>
            <tr>
            <?php if((strpos($row['pojem']), 'Pizza') !== false) { ?>
              <td><font color="red"><?= $row['pojem'] ?></font></td>
            <?php }else{ ?>
              <td><font color="brown"><?= $row['pojem'] ?></font></td>
            <?php } ?>
              <td><font color="brown"><?= $row['kratica'] ?></font></td>
              <td><font color="brown"><?= $row['nem'] ?></font></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not a good solution because $row['pojem'] contains a sentence.